# Sort list-items with subcategories

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have the following code to sort a List like this by the order attribute:

```
<div id="a-categories">
    <a href="blabla" order="2" class="leftCats">Cat 2</a>
    <a href="blabla" order="1" class="leftCats">Cat 1</a>
    <a href="blabla" order="4" class="leftCats">Cat 4</a>
</div>
```

Code:

```
var list = document.id('a-categories');
var listGroupObjects = document.getElementsByClassName('leftCats');

var listGroupArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < listGroupObjects.length; ++i) {
    listGroupArray.push(listGroupObjects[i]);
}

listGroupArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.getAttribute('order') - b.getAttribute('order'));
});

for (var i = 0; i < listGroupArray.length; i++) {
    list.removeChild(listGroupArray[i]);
}

for (var i = 0; i < listGroupArray.length; i++) {
    list.appendChild(listGroupArray[i]);
}
```

This works very finde.
But now I have this:

```
<div id="a-categories">
    <a href="blabla" order="2" class="leftCats">Cat 2</a>
    <a href="blabla" order="1" class="leftCats">Cat 1</a>
    <a href="blabla" order="1" parOrder="2" class="leftCats">Cat 2.1</a>
    <a href="blabla" order="2" parOrder="2" class="leftCats">Cat 2.2</a>
    <a href="blabla" order="4" class="leftCats">Cat 4</a>
</div>
```

It's like subitems. So every item having the "parOrder" attribute is a child. And parOrder gives the order of the parent-item and order of itself.

How can I order it, so that the Childs are ordered itself under the parent item.
In this example it would be:**Edit:**

```
<div id="a-categories">
    <a href="blabla" order="1" class="leftCats">Cat 1</a>
    <a href="blabla" order="2" class="leftCats">Cat 2</a>
    <a href="blabla" order="1" parOrder="2" class="leftCats">Cat 2.1</a>
    <a href="blabla" order="2" parOrder="2" class="leftCats">Cat 2.2</a>
    <a href="blabla" order="4" class="leftCats">Cat 4</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see the logic of how you got to that last result. Why does the `order=4` come after the items with sub categories? I thought the subitem ones would be last since you put them out of order according to their `order` attribute. I was expecting either order 1, 2, 4, then the 2 with sub categories or order 1, order 1 with sub, order 2, order 2 with sub, order 4.

Comment: The ones containing 'parOrder' aren't the one with subcategories. These are the subcategories. e.g. order="1" parOrder="4" means, that it is a sub-category from the item with order="4" (which has no parOrder) and the order="1" says, that its the first sub-category. See my edit.

Comment: I see now, makes a lot more sense. Very good edit.

Comment: You should convert the value of the `order` attribute in the compare function to real numbers otherwise items with `order=1x` will end up in front of items with `order=2/3/4/5...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort by `order` only those items which have no `parOrder` (1-level nodes). Then, while appending items without `parOrder`, you can find items which are "child" items for the current, sort them by `order` and append. Just a simple nested loop.

By the way, you don't need to `removeChild` if you want to sort items. Executing `appendChild` on existing DOM element will remove it from the original location before inserting in a new location.

Something like this:

```
var list = document.getElementById('a-categories');
var listGroupObjects = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.leftCats:not([parOrder])'));

listGroupObjects.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.getAttribute('order') - b.getAttribute('order'));
});

for (var i = 0; i < listGroupObjects.length; i++)
{
    list.appendChild(listGroupObjects[i]);

    var sublistGroupObjects = [].slice.call(list.querySelectorAll(".leftCats[parOrder='" + listGroupObjects[i].getAttribute('order') + "']"));

    sublistGroupObjects.sort(function (a, b) {
        return (a.getAttribute('order') - b.getAttribute('order'));
    });

    for (var j = 0; j < sublistGroupObjects.length; j++) 
    {
        list.appendChild(sublistGroupObjects[j]);    
    }
}
```

In other words, it sorts 1-level nodes and gets 1, 2, 4. Then, it appends 1 - no child items; appends 2 - two child nodes are being sorted and inserted after the current one; appends 4.

Of course, this code can be easily optimized by removing a duplicating code which sorts items. It's up to your fantasy. Here is just a working [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/61qxf53d/2/).